# Floating-point subtractive identities

Tags: floating-point, language-agnostic, ieee-754

As I understand it, in IEEE floating point, the following identity really does always apply:

```
x - 0.0 == x
```

But the following mathematical identity may not necessarily always apply, due to issues regarding signed zero:

```
0.0 - x == -x
```

Is this correct?

Comment: There is another difference: In IEEE-754 (2008), the *negate* operation is (like the *absolute value* and *copysign* operations) defined in terms of bit string manipulation, and will therefore modify the "sign bit" of NaNs (see section 6.3 of the standard).

Comment: Both `x - 0.0 == x` and `0.0 - x == -x` evaluate to false if `x` is a NaN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(+0) − (+0) returns (−0) when rounding towards −∞, but (+0) in all other rounding modes. So replacing `x - 0.0` with `x` will deliver bit-wise identical results *only if* the rounding mode towards −∞ ("down") is excluded. However, since (-0) and (+0) compare equal under IEEE-754 semantics, `x - 0.0 == x` will hold in all rounding modes.

−(+0) results in (−0), whereas (+0) − (+0) returns (+0) in all rounding modes other than when rounding towards −∞. So replacing `0.0 - x` with `-x` will deliver bit-wise identical results only when the rounding mode is towards −∞ ("down"). However, since (-0) and (+0) compare equal under IEEE-754 semantics, `0.0 -x == -x` will hold in all rounding modes.

As far as bit-wise equality (rather than floating-point equality comparison) is concerned, it should also be noted that in IEEE-754 (2008), the *negate* operation is (like the *absolute value* and *copysign* operations) defined in terms of bit string manipulation, and will therefore modify the "sign bit" of NaNs (see section 6.3 of the standard). On platforms that implement pass-through of NaN payloads, the results of negation and subtraction from zero therefore differ at bit level if `x` is a NaN.

Answer (score 3):

njuffa's answer provides a nice analysis. Bottom line, if you simply use `==` that does not distinguish between `+0` and `-0`, and if you ignore `NaN` values, both identities hold. But you can tell the expressions apart based on rounding-mode by looking at the bit-patterns as you can get `-0` in one case and `0` in the other.

Here's another example that I always found surprising. Consider the definition of `fma`:

```
fma (a, b, c) = a * b + c; but with only one rounding instead of two
```

If you put in `c = 0` in the above identity, you might expect the following to hold:

```
fma (a, b, 0) == a * b
```

Alas, it fails if the multiplication generates `-0`, since `-0 + 0` is `+0`. On the left-hand side, you'd get `+0`, on the right-hand side you'd get `-0`.

Again, these would compare equal using regular `==`, but if you're interested in bit-wise equality, you have to watch out for the sign of zero!